# UICollectionViewCell higher y than UICollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a `UICollectionView` in my app, that I initialize with the following code:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
                                                     collectionViewLayout:layout];
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
[self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"normalCell"];
[self.collectionView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[self.collectionView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
```

Then I added all the protocol methods:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.frame.size.height);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 3;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"normalCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    UIEdgeInsets safeInsets = self.tabBarController.view.safeAreaInsets;

    NSLog(@"Top: %f", safeInsets.top);

    self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, safeInsets.top, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-safeInsets.top);
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Now, the `UICollectionView` is placed perfectly within my view. The `UICollectionViewCell` however, starts much higher than the `UICollectionView`.

In the screenshot below you can see the behaviour. In blue, you can see the `UICollectionViewCell` and in yellow, you can see the `UICollectionView`. As you can see it seems to have a higher y-coordinate then the `UICollectionView`.

[image]

I've been busting my head for a couple of hours now, but I can't seem to figure out why it's doing this. Any ideas?

Comment: collectionView has a clearColor not yellow according to code ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan Sorry, I just made it yellow for the screenshot.

Comment: it's not full screen also according to code can use update code also with method you create the collection in

Comment: @user4992124 here you set cell height according to tabbarcontroller so it higher than cell height just set height with cell

Comment: How about set `clipsTobounds ` to `true` , for `UICollectionView` ?

Comment: @RealmOfFire That was the exact problem. If you add it as an answer, I can accept it. :)

Comment: @user4992124 accept my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you set cell height according to tabbarcontroller so it higher than cell height just set height with cell.